# System.InvalidOperationException: enumeration operation may not execute - comes intermittently

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

we make an API call and receive the response from a script. while receiving it getting an error

```
{
    "ClassName": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "Message": "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."
}
```

the most strange part is I am not getting this error regularly, if I make 50 calls in between I get this error (intermittently), any idea ?

updated: its happening after we receive the response from API, we are manipulating our dynamic request based on the api response in the below manner

```
 private JToken GetPEmail(dynamic verb, dynamic inputProfile)
        {
            verb.Log("GetProfileEmail Method", "Start", null, null, null, null, false);
            var emailList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>();// creating custom response 

            foreach (var item in inputProfile.Emails)
            {
                verb.Log("Get EmailId for " + item, "start", null, null, null, null, false);
                var pID = GetEmailId(verb, Convert.ToString(item.EmailAddress)); // db call 
                emailList.Add(new
                {
                    EmailAddress = item.Email,
                    IsPreferred = item.IsP,
                    EmailPOCID = Convert.ToString(pID)
                });

                verb.Log("Get EmailId for " + item, "End", Convert.ToString(pID), null, null, null, false);
            }
```

Comment: You're modifying a collection (adding or removing items from it) while you're iterating through it (by using `foreach`, for example). Please provide your API server code.

Comment: @Llama okay, but why it is coming intermittently , I mean it should come with every call right

Comment: How can I possibly answer that? It depends on your API server code. Perhaps the collection is only altered in specific scenarios.

Comment: I expect that `inputProfile.Emails` is changing while you're iterating through it. Presumably somewhere outside of `GetPEmail` you're modifying it at the same time as `GetPEmail` is running.

Comment: @Llama oh yes but its at the end as a part of ResetInput method where we are removing all the input fields except the additional required part input.outputResponse = response; how can I solve this now, have to make prior call async let it wait then execute ResetInput method ?

Comment: The simplest option would be to make a duplicate of `inputProfile.Emails` within the method (e.g. `List<yourEmailType> emails = inputProfile.Emails.ToList(); foreach (var item in emails);` A better option is to pass in a static (in the sense that it won't change again, not `static`) list in the first place.

Comment: @Llama inputProfile.Emails.ToList() will not work,  inputProfile.Emails comes as JArray, hw to make a copy of it ?

Comment: It [works fine for me](https://rextester.com/AXZS63988). There's also [`DeepClone`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_DeepClone.htm), but that might be overkill.

Comment: sorry for the long chain, everything is type dynamic but the main input is deserialized to Jobject and subsequently inputProfile.Emails as JArray so if I use the above solution I wont able to access Emails attributes

Comment: It's at this stage I'd probably just recommend deserializing to classes. Your current technique seems to be causing issues for you.